# Magento 2.2.1 Search Returns No Products

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Upgraded to Magento 2.2.1 from 2.2.0, refreshed all caches, indexes, etc. Everything seems to be working fine except when using the frontend search it returns no products regardless.

I checked the `search_query` table and it is showing the queries and that it should have results.

Has anyone encountered this or have any suggestions that I could try to correct this?

Comment: What search engine are you using? The default on or Elasticsearch?

Comment: Default MySQL, this morning I'm going to begin logging out the  template & search result blocks.